# Intellij Code Completion for all setter/getter methods of local variable object

Tags: java, intellij-idea, editor

I did try searching for this, but honestly the terms to actually search are escaping me. A small code snippet followed by the question.

```
Public class Person {

   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   ...
}
```

In **another object that uses this person object** I would like to be able to expand all the setters methods in Intellij.

```
public class PersonAssembler { 
    public static Person assemblePerson(SomeOtherObject someOtherObject) {

    Person person = new Person;

    //intellj would provide this below.
    person.setFirstName();
    person.setLastName();
    //end of what intellj provides.

    return person;
}
```

Is this even possible?  I have looked through the keyboard short cuts, etc.  I have been using intellij for a while, so just wondered if anyone had some insight on this.

I was hoping for column edit mode, then code completion and perhaps a shift+down arrow to select multiple completions, but no luck.  Which is not surprising.  I would hate to have to write that in the GUI.

Edit:  I added some clarification and honestly forgot about this question.  The answers have nothing to do with the actual question if read carefully.  I am not speaking of the Generate context menu.

Answer (score 50):

In your project, right-click anywhere on the typing screen, and click 'Generate...' and then 'Getter and Setter'. Then, hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click on the fields you wish to create getters and setters for, then click on 'OK'.

Comment: He does not seem to want to generate getters/setters - he wants to generate setter calls in the client class instead.

Comment: is there a way to automize this? cant find the appropriate keymap shortcut.

Comment: Good solution when creating a new struct-like class

Comment: My kingdom for a "select all" button on this screen!

Comment: In my intelliJ, there's no 'Generate' when I right-click, any thoughts?

Answer (score 27):

This is an old question, but maybe it helps someone.

Also, it's not a "single-click" action, but...

Steps to follow:

- Go to Class file
- Open Structure view (left panel)
- Select all setters (sort alphabetically if needed) and copy
- Go back to your destination class/method
- Paste copied
- Edit (in column mode) to include `person.` at the beginning of each class and `()` at the end.

Comment: Very nice! This actually is very insightful and works very well.  Thanks!

Comment: command + n is the shortcut for creating getters/setters, but that is not what @BlakeDunn was asking for.

Comment: Still helpful in 2024! Wasn't aware you can copy method names from structure panel.

Answer (score 18):

Shortcut for creating getter setter is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> in Intellij.

Answer (score 12):

when your curser is inside your newly created class then you can press ALT+Insert -- a dialog should appear and you can then select Getter and Setter

[image]

Comment: In `Mac` it's `Ctrl`+`return`

Comment: it is possible in Intellij to custom setup the keyboard shortcuts - however It I prefer default

Answer (score 8):

This plugin may help [GenerateAllSetter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9360-generateallsetter)

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> where you want to use and it will generate setter calls for you.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure how to do this in IntelliJ, but I will link you to a framework that makes these kinds of things so much smoother in Java: Project Lombok

take your code for example, it will look like this:

```
public class Person {
    @Setter
    @Getter
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

there is a pluging for intellij that fixes it so you dont get any annoying warnings as well.

http://projectlombok.org/

Answer (score 5):

here is my plugin [genSets](https://github.com/yoke233/genSets)

`Foo foo = new Foo();`

code like this

`foo.allSet`

will generate

```
foo.setName();
foo.setAge();
foo.setBar();
foo.setTest();
foo.setLike();
```

Comment: It there a compiled plugin for this?

Comment: @aristotll If you go to [releases](https://github.com/yoke233/genSets/releases) on the Github page you can download the compiled plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Shortcut for Windows `Alt + Insert`

Shortcut for Mac `Command + N`

then choose `getter and setter`

Answer (score 1):

Continuation to `Michael Jarvis` answer:

So I am in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.4 (Community Edition)
and I realized it is important to select all the fields first in order for `right-click` or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>` to have the menu Property (getter and setter)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In mac you can insert the getter by pressing ctrl + return -> selecting getters, setters or both -> selecting the variable you want it and press return

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that does this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/9360-generateallsetter

Go to File > Settings > Plugins and search for a plugin GenerateAllSetter (See the link above) and install it

**NOTE**: It does not need the IDE to restart.

Once the plugin is installed, create an instance of your object/dto. Place your cursor on the initialization line of code and IntelliJ IDEA
show the yellow suggestions light-bulb.
Click the light bulb(or use Alt+ Enter) and suggestions will appear. Here you can choose to generate setter with or without default value.
See images.

[image: Setter call suggestions]

Below are images of the resulting code genarated (both with and without defaults)

Setters without default values

[image: Setters without default values]

Setters with deafult values

[image: Setters with deafult values]

Answer (score 0):

[This is an example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg71i.gif)

I wrote a Jar, it can quickly and automatically generate Java dto set method calls, including import and new statements.

You can try this: https://github.com/Adrninistrator/GenSetterCalls

Add dependeny: "com.github.adrninistrator:GenSetterCalls:0.0.1"

1. Copy the Java/class file information.
2. Execute the class "com.github.adrninistrator.gensettercalls.gen.GenSetterCallsAuto".
3. Then you can paste the generated setter code.