# ArrayAdapter.getPosition is not finding my object

Tags: android

New to Android, I got a simple application with spinners and associated ArrayAdapters working: when things get selected, I seem to be able and trigger some calculations. I am then saving the current selected item.

At some point, I retrieve the saved value, and want to position the spinner at that value: basically setPosition() the spinner to that object.

I have found lots of tutorials with the same format I have: use the getPosition() on the ArrayAdapter, and pass in the object you are looking for... Trouble is, it keeps returning -1 (not found).

Debugging, I have verified that the object I pass is not null, and so is the ArrayAdapter, and also the ArrayAdapter getCount returns me the items it should have (so it's not empty).

I'm at loss. Appreciate any... pointers? :-)

/* ArrayAdapter class looks like this*/

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {
    // Constructor
    MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<MyClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }
}
```

/* Fragment looks like this*/

```
final MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(
                                 requireActivity(), 
                                 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                                 objects);
Spinner mySpinner = fragment_view.findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
mySpinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);

// assume I have one "object" of MyClass,
// and want to search for it in "MyAdapter"

int spinnerPosition = mAdapter.getPosition(objectToBeFound);  // returns -1
mySpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#getPosition(T)..See this and for testing purpose,i suggest you to iterate the adapter items and check whether you have that item or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapter internally works with `List`

```
public int getPosition(@Nullable T item) {
    return mObjects.indexOf(item);
}
```

so `getPosition` internally depends upon [`List#indexOf(T)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) and which relies on `equals` method

```
(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))
```

so you are getting `-1` because you haven't implemented `equals` and `hashcode` method properly in `MyClass` so implement both methods and you will be able to get the precise index.

Referene:

[Use Auto Generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988504/intellij-code-completion-for-all-setter-getter-methods-of-local-variable-object)

[difference between equals() and hashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446763/difference-between-equals-and-hashcode)

Comment: That was it. Thank you! Now, I really wonder why I haven't found this information anywhere... If you have a *good* android guide somewhere, I'd like to know about. Thanks again!

Comment: basically is used everywhere when searching is used on POJO objects though sometimes you have go through the source code to understand the inner working to write a solution and happy to help!

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh can you please provide me a complete example on this? 
It help a new Android Developer.

Comment: I get a good Example to implemented equals and hashcode method properly 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/